# onclick set attribute required to input

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I want to set the required attribute to the input when I click the checkbox above. And when I click another checkbox above required attribute must be removed. I tried: setAttribute.required = true; .required(true) but nothing worked for me

```js
function unHide() {
  document.getElementById('question_p').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('datepicker_psych').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('datapicker_psych').required = true;
}

function hide() {
  document.getElementById('question_p').style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById('datepicker_psych').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<label><input class="form-check-input" onclick="unHide()"  type="radio" name="psych" required value="1">Yes</label>
<label><input class="form-check-input" onclick="hide()" type="radio" name="psych">No</label>
<p style="text-align: left; display: none;" id="question_p">TEXT</p>
<input style="display: none; width: 100%" placeholder="dd.mm.rrrr" class="form-control" name="date_psych" type="text" id="datepicker_psych"><br>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `.setAttribute("required", "required")`

Comment: And `.removeAttribute("required")`

Comment: okay so i put those two commands and when I check the source code of the webpage I cant see required attribute when clicked chceckbox

Comment: You don't see it in source code, you see it in the DOM inspector.

Comment: You have a typo: `datapicker_psych` should be `datepicker_psych`. Is that a copying error or in the real code?

Comment: This is real code. Oh thank I did not noticed that I have a typo in this. Happend to me often :)

Comment: Okay working. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Didn't you get an error in the JavaScript console indicating that `getElementById()` returned null? That's how I discovered it when I ran the snippet above.

Comment: Actually I didn't, there was some warnings but not errors related to this.

Comment: When you click on the Hide button you should have gotten the error `Cannot set property 'required' of null`

Comment: I checked the errors and there is nothing like that.

Comment: Maybe in your real HTML you have another element with the typo ID? So it's adding the required property to an unrelated element.

Comment: It is possible, yeah